# How to edit this Gravity form stripe addon code so that I can charge the credit card as well?

Tags: stripe-payments, gravity-forms-plugin

Gravity Forms has a Stripe add-on that connects to Stripe and allows for 1-time and recurring purchases. The functionality works great, except that for 1-time purchases, it does not create Customers in Stripe. (By comparison, it DOES create Stripe Customers for recurring purchases.).

https://docs.gravityforms.com/create-customer-stripe-without-payment/.

The issue with this bit of code is that it only allows you to create a customer. I need to both create a Customer AND charge the credit card.
The code snippets are below:

```
add_filter( 'gform_stripe_customer_id', function ( $customer_id, $feed, $entry, $form ) {
GFCommon::log_debug( __METHOD__ . '(): running.' );
if ( rgars( $feed, 'meta/transactionType' ) == 'product' && rgars( $feed, 'meta/feedName' ) == 'feed name goes here' ) {
    GFCommon::log_debug( __METHOD__ . '(): Working for feed ' . rgars( $feed, 'meta/feedName' ) );
    $customer_meta = array();

    $email_field = rgars( $feed, 'meta/receipt_field' );
    if ( ! empty( $email_field ) && strtolower( $email_field ) !== 'do not send receipt' ) {
        $customer_meta['email'] = gf_stripe()->get_field_value( $form, $entry, $email_field );
    }

    $customer = gf_stripe()->create_customer( $customer_meta, $feed, $entry, $form );
    GFCommon::log_debug( __METHOD__ . '(): Returning Customer ID ' . $customer->id );

    return $customer->id;
}

return $customer_id;
}, 10, 4 );

add_filter( 'gform_stripe_charge_authorization_only', function ( $authorization_only, $feed ) 
{
if ( rgars( $feed, 'meta/feedName' ) == 'feed name goes here' ) {
    GFCommon::log_debug( __METHOD__ . '(): running for feed ' . rgars( $feed, 'meta/feedName' ) );
    return true;
}

return $authorization_only;
}, 10, 2 );

add_filter( 'gform_stripe_charge_pre_create', function( $charge_meta, $feed, $submission_data, $form, $entry ) {
if ( rgars( $feed, 'meta/feedName' ) == 'feed name goes here' ) {
    GFCommon::log_debug( __METHOD__ . '(): running for feed ' . rgars( $feed, 'meta/feedName' ) );
    $charge_meta['setup_future_usage'] = 'off_session';
}

return $charge_meta;
}, 10, 5 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always [create the customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create?lang=php) yourself and then provide it when creating a [payment intent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create?lang=php#create_payment_intent-customer) (or a [charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create?lang=php#create_charge-customer)). Whether Gravity supports passing in a customer I don't know. You'll have to reach our to them to ask if that is supported and how to do it.

Comment: Thank you Nolan for your answer. But I have another problem. The code I have mentioned, it returns the id of the customer. How can I edit it so that it returns the email of the customer?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what code you're referring to, but it seems like it might just be a case of `return $customer->id;` to `return $customer->email;` (assuming you set the customer email).